# Python dataframe if a particular row is bad then drop previous n rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame. I check if a row is good or bad. If a row is bad, I want to drop this and the previous two rows (n=2). In my actual problem n=60. I have a working solution. Is there a better way? checking if my solution is the pythonic way of doing it.
My code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,20,30,40,50],'isBad?':[False,False,True,False,False]})

df = 
    A  isBad?
0  10   False
1  20   False
2  30    True
3  40   False
4  50   False
```

Expected answer:

```
df = 
    A  isBad?
1  40   False
2  50   False
```

My solution:

```
bad_row_index = pd.concat(df.loc[i-2:i:1] for i,r in xdf.iterrows() if r['isBad?']==True).drop_duplicates(keep='first').index
df[~df.index.isin(bad_row_index)].reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
df = 
    A  isBad?
1  40   False
2  50   False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question!

After a bit of exploration, I came up with a pretty short solution:

```
subset = df[~(df['isBad?'] | df['isBad?'].shift(-1) | df['isBad?'].shift(-2))]
```

Output:

```
>>> subset
    A  isBad?
3  40   False
4  50   False
```

A dynamic version of that (so that you can change the number of previous rows dropped without manually writing more `.shift()`s):

```
import functools as ft

n = 2  # Drop all True's and the 2 previous ones
subset = df[~ft.reduce(lambda x,y: x|y, [df['isBad?'].shift(-i) for i in range(n+1)])]
```

Output:

```
>>> subset
    A  isBad?
3  40   False
4  50   False
```

Comment: My apologies. In this problem n=2. What if n=60? I have modified my question.

Comment: If n=60, use my dynamic version and set the `n` variable to `60`, @Mainland.

Comment: Wow! your solution looks simple than mine. Can you explain what this `reduce` is doing here? I appreciate you explaining those new things. You are using `lambda` here for creating iteration, it is understandable. Also, you selected two variables `x,y` and you made `x or y choice`. Surprisingly, they were not mapped to anything after that. You are shifting `n` times.

Comment: Yes, I'll explain. `reduce` basically takes a function and a list, and for each item in the list, it calls the function, passing the current item of the list as the first parameter, and _the value returned from the previous call of the function_. So `x` is the current item of the list, and `y` is the accumulated one. (You can read more about reduce functions online.) `x|y` is special Pandas syntax that takes to columns, of the same length, containing boolean values, and returns a new column containing True for each item if the item in either column is True, or False if both are False...

Comment: ...You can read more about that online too (search for `pandas bitwise or operator`). Essentially all that the code does is create a list contained all the shifts of the `isBad?` column, and combines all those shifts.

Comment: This is totally new time. I have learned about a new function `reduce` today. Thanks. Now it is not clear to me about what's going on inside that function. I have to spend some time on it. Thanks a lot.